# Group data by calendar month

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm very new on Javascript and I'm trying to learn D3.

I've got a `json` file (or a `csv`) with the following structure:

```
[{"tot_b": "172", "tot_a": "91", "datetime": "2012-01-01"},
{"tot_b": "116", "tot_a": "69", "datetime": "2012-01-02"},
{"tot_b": "122", "tot_a": "88", "datetime": "2012-02-01"},
{"tot_b": "30", "tot_a": "116", "datetime": "2012-02-02"},
{"tot_b": "19", "tot_a": "99", "datetime": "2012-03-01"},
{"tot_b": "116", "tot_a": "84", "datetime": "2012-03-02"},]
```

Among others, the aim is to show a number of bar charts with the values of `tot_a`, `tot_b` and `tot_b/tot_a`.

How do I read the json file and have a data structure where I sum the data corresponding to dates in the same calendar month? For example I'd like something like:

```
{
    'data': ['2012-01', '2012-02', '2012-03'],
    'tot_a': [91+69, 88+116, 99+84],
    'tot_b': [172+116, 122+30, 19+116],
}
```

I've looked in SO, but I haven't find anything similar to this. Any reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`d3.nest`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nests) is your friend for summarizing your data like this.

First, rollup your data to get the totals for `tot_a` and `tot_b`:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.datetime.split('-').slice(0, 2).join('-'); })
  .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
  .rollup(function(leaves) {
      return {
        tot_b: d3.sum(leaves, function(d){ return d.tot_b }),
        tot_a: d3.sum(leaves, function(d){ return d.tot_a; })
      };
  })
  .entries(data);
```

Then, unwrap it into the data structure you specified:

```
var keys = nested_data.map(function(d){ return d.key; });
var bar_chart_data = {
    data: keys,
    tot_a: nested_data.map(function(d){ return d.values.tot_a; }),
    tot_b: nested_data.map(function(d){ return d.values.tot_b; })
};
```

And you get:

```
{
 "data":["2012-01","2012-02","2012-03"],
 "tot_a":[160,204,183],
 "tot_b":[288,152,135]
}
```

Here's a demo in a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rztt5xqx/).